# Match GPS track polyline to existing polyline on Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, gps, polyline

I'm stumped on a question and I'm curious if anyone can guide me in the right direction.
I have two polylines on a Leaflet map.

1. A smooth polyline that follows the preset track
2. A GPS tracker polyline that follows the same track, but is not smooth due to GPS signal.

I've shown the current situation in the first half of my screenshot.

What I'm trying to figure out is this. How to:
a) match the GPS tracker to the preset polyline (like drawing in 2nd half of screenshot)
b) pass a variable to the preset polyline when the GPS tracker passes over it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks very much!
[Screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1q2V.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want but here is a way how can add the GPSMarker on the Line:

`smoothLine` is the correct line `L.polyline()`

```
var GPSmarker = L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map)
var GPSmarkerOnLine = L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map)
map.on('click',function(e){
    GPSmarker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
  var x = smoothLine.closestLayerPoint(map.latLngToLayerPoint(e.latlng)) // convert latlng to point and get closest point on the line
  var ll = map.layerPointToLatLng(x); // convert back to latlng
  GPSmarkerOnLine.setLatLng(ll);
  if(x.distance < 5){ // Distance lower then 5px or ll.distanceTo(e.latlng) < 5 --> Lower then 5 Meters
    console.log('MATCHED')
    L.marker(ll).addTo(map);
  }
})
```

With this code you have one GPS Marker instead a GPS Line

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/tpogj6wb/